# A slight modification in Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

Suppose $m_1, m_2, m_3,\ldots, m_k > 1$ and not necessarily pairwise relatively prime. Also $a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_k\in\Bbb Z$. What can we say about the solutions of the following congruence equations:

$\begin{align*}
x&=a_1\mod m_1\\
x&=a_2\mod m_2\\
 &\phantom{1}\vdots\\
x&=a_k\mod m_k
\end{align*}$

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your question and [visit here.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Answer (score 1):

What is known  is that there exists  solutions if and only if
$$\forall\,1\le i,j\le k,\qquad a_i\equiv a_j\mod\gcd(m_i,m_j).$$
When these conditions are satisfied, the solution is unique $\bmod\operatorname{lcm}(m_1,m_2,\dots,m_k)$